# Difference between these sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, kanji

> このお酒飲んでみて
>
> この酒を飲んで見て

I’m not sure if the second one is even grammatical. I need some help making out the meaning of the two.

**Edit:**

I think both sentences mean please drink this sake but they are written differently. I would like a comparison between the two in terms of grammar and semantics.

Comment: You changed three things (remove お, add を, みて→見て), was there one change in particular you were interested in?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie As I mentioned above, I'm not even sure if those changes were valid. So are you telling me that both sentences are grammatical?

Comment: if you look at tps://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic it says, direct translations are off-topic. if you want to know about what でみて means that is easily google-able.

Comment: It's better to focus your question on one particular change.

Comment: @NathanHughes I think I know what the sentences mean. They mean please drink this sake. I would like to know if there's any difference between the two. Basically, I would like a comparison in terms of grammar and semantics.

Comment: well grammatically leaving out the を direct object particle in the first one is flat-out even-i-can-see-that-this-is wrong. leaving out the honorific preceding お is maybe not as totally wrong but makes this significantly rougher in tone, so pretty much wrong for most occasions. and i think using 見 is probably old-timey.

Comment: @NathanHughes Is it really flat out wrong? I often hear people say 何してるの. を is omitted here after 何.

Comment: it wasn't clear you were asking about verbal omissions. people do speak ungrammatically. :-|

Comment: @Nathan を-omission is totally fine and often preferred in colloquial Japanese.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie: agreed, I just think the question should have been upfront about that aspect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> このお酒飲んでみて

First, let's fix one error: このお酒**を**飲んでみて。
Omitting the を is possible but I don't recommend it. It just doesn't sound good if a foreigner try to speak lazy Japanese.

The お before 酒（さけ）is an honorific prefix like in おなまえ (name). It's a good idea to use that prefix whenever you're talking about items, things or any nouns that belong to others.

Next, 飲んで（のんで)just means drinking. ~て みて is try to do ~. 
So the sentence means "Try to drink this alcoholic drink." As far as I know the みて is written as Hiragana since 見る carries the meaning to see.

That should answer the question, which mix out of both sentences is needed in order to have a fully correct sentence.

Comment: を-dropping is extremely common in colloquial Japanese, and I think “lazy” is bit too strong of a value judgment about it. In a casual setting このお酒飲んでみて is totally fine, regardless of if you are native, non-native, foreigner, whatever. In fact I’d say it has a better ring to it than the version with を in that scenario.

Comment: is みて the same as 見て ?

Comment: In my understanding it depends on the sentence. Sometimes dropping it sound natural sometimes it doesn't. As a foreigner it is difficult to know when and when not to use. That's why I don't recommend it. On the other hand it's also true that the neutral honorific form we're all learning from text books and teachers is rarely used by native speakers.

Comment: 見る means "to see" although it has the same pronunciation. ~てみる is to try something. For example "(please) try to see" would be 見てみて（ください）。

Comment: @Thomas hmm this is really bothering me. If used individually, can みて mean to see? I want to know because in my native tongue we have verb + see to suggest attempt So I wonder if this て みて is something I can relate to.

Comment: @Will the verb 見る "to see" has nothing to do with the みる "to try". If you use it, you need to make sure to use it with the verb's て-form.
来てみて = try to come
食べてみて = try to eat
見てみて = try to see
飲んでみて = try to drink

Comment: Another addtion, you can of course use different forms of みる.
食べてみたい I want to try to eat
食べてみた I tried to eat
食べてみないで Try not to eat.

Comment: Um, saying “the verb 見る "to see" has nothing to do with the みる "to try"” seems between an overstatement and incorrect?  The etymology of 〜てみる is indeed 〜て見る (in the sense of “do X and see (if it goes okay)” → 〜てみる), and in fact, you can still write 〜て見る and be understood, it’s just usually considered poor style to kanjify your auxiliary verbs. (Though some people choose to do so anyways for intentional stylistic reasons occasionally, like making your text look heavier.)

Comment: Also, the difference between お酒 and 酒 is not that お酒 is someone else’s drink (i.e., an honorific usage), but rather お酒 has been lexicalized to mean “an alcoholic drink” and you can (and generally always should) use it to refer to alcoholic drinks, including your own. 酒 is usable for this meaning but it’s a less refined word. “美化語” is the word for this general phenomenon.

Comment: Yet another note is that neither 酒 or お酒 refer specifically to the drink referred to as “sake” in English, so I’d say that is not a great translation. (“Sake” is 日本酒 in Japanese.) 酒 and お酒 just refer to alcohol / alcoholic drinks in general.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thank you so much for clarifying. It makes so much more sense to me now.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks, I've overseen that and edited. Of course it means alcohol.

As for the 見る and みる is a different meaning in terms of usage and as a grammar, I wanted to clarify that. But you are correct again, in the sense of "to see (if it works out)" works perfectly in the English interpretation. In German this works too with "mal sehen".

Comment: @DariusJahandarie (Though some people choose to do so anyways for intentional stylistic reasons occasionally, like making your text look heavier.) -> I think it's a good excuse to practice Kanji too, so I usually kanjify as much as I can. As long as you are aware it's just an exercise and you shouldn't do it depending on the context, no problem.